# Assigning value to symbol in particular index in symbolic array

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am creating a matrix of symbolic variables (`A`) and then creating an expression using the variables in this matrix (`X`). I intend to set the value of the symbol in a particular index in `A` (for example, in my code I do `A(1,1) = 11`), and then I want that to be reflected in the expression. However, when I do `subs(X)`, I find that the symbol is not replaced. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Below is what I am trying:

```
>> A = sym('X', [2 2])

A =

[ X1_1, X1_2]
[ X2_1, X2_2]

>> X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11

X =

10*X1_1 + 11*X2_2

>> A(1,1)=11

A =

[   11, X1_2]
[ X2_1, X2_2]

>> subs(X)

ans =

10*X1_1 + 11*X2_2
```

I could of course do `X1_1 = 2`. My problem is that this is not amenable to looping. I'd like to set the values in a loop. Obviously `A(*,*)=*` is amenable to looping. Is there any way to set the value of `X1_1` indirectly?

Edit: To achieve this, I can redefine `X` after setting the value of `A(*,*)`. However this is not an option for me. Defining `X` is a very costly operation. Doing it multiple times is out of the question for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating an index in `A` with a value, you can use the symbolic variable in the index of `A` to substitute that value in `X`:

```
>> A = sym('X', [2 2]);
>> X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11;
>> X = subs(X, A(1,1), 11)

X =

11*X2_2 + 110
```

And if you want to do this for all the symbolic variables in `A`, you don't even have to use a loop. Just one call to [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) will work:

```
>> Avalues = [11 0; 1 10];  % The values corresponding to symbolic variables in A
>> X = subs(X, A, Avalues)

X =

220
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you set the value in a particular index in A, just do `X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11` one more time, which is amenable to looping.

For example:

```
A = sym('X', [2 2]);
X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11;
A(1,1) = 11;
X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11
```

It will update `X`:

```
X =

11*X2_2 + 110
```

Example for looping:

```
A = sym('X', [2 2]);
X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11;

for i = 1:2
    for j = 1:2
        A(i,j) = 11;
        X = A(1,1)*10 + A(2,2)*11
    end
end
```

Output:

```
X =

11*X2_2 + 110


X =

11*X2_2 + 110


X =

11*X2_2 + 110


X =

231
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option for me. Defining X again is very costly. I need to set many different values to ```A(*, *)``` and X is a very costly operation. X is actually calculating eigenvalues of a large matrix so I shouldn't execute it too many times.